# Bash - redirected string not showing in output

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdin

I'm automating compilation and execution of C++ programs (+100 programs) which some of them require user interaction.

Here is a sample of C++ program that requires user to insert a string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string name;

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "your name is: " << name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here what I need is to compile it, execute it and redirect the output of the program to another file:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o practice practice.cpp
```

To automate the input insertion I run the program as follows:

```
./practice <<< $(echo "Brian") >> result.txt
```

I know there are different ways of redirecting a string into program's STDIN like

```
echo "Brian" | ./practice >> result.txt
```

But all of them generate the following output:

```
Enter your name: your name is: Brian
```

What I want is to see below output instead:

```
Enter your name: Brian
your name is: Brian
```

I want the redirected string to appear in the output of the file, right after the line program requires user interaction.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this?

```
cout << "Enter your name: ";
cin >> name;
cout << name << endl;

cout << "your name is: " << name << endl;
```

Here's how it looks on my end after compiling:

```
$ echo "foo" | ./a.out 
Enter your name: foo
your name is: foo
```

*Note:* 
Haven't used C++ in ages!

Comment: after your edit: this can be considerable in C++ approach, but I'm still looking forward to a bash scripting solution

Comment: @BrianSP2 this isn't a bash problem, it's a C++ problem. I don't think you'll find a bash solution. The C++ program isn't written to show its input, the only reason you see it when running manually is because the terminal shows what you type. So when you pipe input to your program, that input is processed but isn't shown. You will have to change the C++ code to change this behavior.

Comment: after some thinking your words do completely sense :) accepting the answer